# Access application context in a storage class in Android

Tags: android, preferences

I have an app on Android 4.0.  It uses the PreferenceManager class to -- among other things -- let the user specify how many decimal places of a number to show.

```
mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Generally I have no problem getting the app context in order to access the Preference Manager.   My problem is that I have a class (let's call it Record) that isn't subclassing anything that has the app context;  it's just a storage class, but it does have a field "NumDecPlaces".  Right now, when I instantiate the class from within my app I just pass in the user's #dec places preference.  It would be nice if Record could access the Preference manager directly.  I suppose I could always instantiate Record with a pointer to the context from which it was created, but that's a lot to remember ;-)

So right now Record subclasses nothing.  Any recommendations on what I can do to it to allow it to see the app context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the `Context` object in the constructor. So whenever you try to use that class it will ask you pass a `Context` object and then use that to get `SharedPreferences`

For eg.

```
public Record(Context context)
{
  mContext = context;

  mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext)
}
```

Comment: Yah, this was my first reaction to the problem.  As I mentioned I was just trying to avoid having to "remember" to instantiate with the context.  It's really not a big deal, though, and it happens pretty much everywhere else in Android development so I don't know why I balked.

Comment: Yes you will either need to pass the `Context` object or the `SharedPrefrences` object in your constructor.

Comment: ...and i'm really complaining too much about the extra work.  Eclipse is pretty good at reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do @Apoorv's suggestion or you can create another class that specifically stores the application context.

```
public class ContextResolver {

    private static Context context;

    public static void setContext(Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null");
        } else if (context instanceof android.app.Activity) {
            context = androidContext.getApplicationContext();
        } else if (context instanceof android.content.Context) {
            context = androidContext;
        }
    }
    public Context getContext() {
       return context;
    }
}
```

Now you need to call setContext() in the first activity that will be launched **once**.

```
public class MyFirstActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate() {
         ContextResolver.setContext(this);
    }
}
```

Now you can retrieve the Context from any part of your code. So in your Record class you can just do this:

```
mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ContextResolver.getContext());
```

Comment: This is interesting.  I'll try it tonight and weigh it against the just-pass-in-a-context option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend a class with Application, which will be global to the whole application and you can set the context in that class as a member variable and that context will be global to the whole application

Eg. class A extends Application{......}